# Getting exception while using NSURLSession

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsurlsession

I am getting **"General exception Data tasks are not supported in background sessions"** exception while trying to send appended data using HTTPPOST Request in NSURLSession. I want to know what causing this exception?

Answer (score 1):

as it said, background nsurlsession doesn't support data task. you can always use a downloadTask to replace a data task. the server json/xml response will be downloaded to phone.